# UWP call a javascript in C# and get a return value

Tags: javascript, c#, web, uwp

I am developing a `UWP` project with a simple `web view`. In my HTML page sometimes appears this code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function myjavascriptfn() 
  {
    var strValue= "test";
    return strValue
  }
```

I would like to call this function from code and get the result back. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: try my answer, it will work for you

Comment: The [WebView control sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=722922) shows how to do this in scenario 3: Invoke Script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
Page.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = "<script>myjavascriptfn();</script>" });
```

if you are using a web view control then use this:-

```
string returnValue = await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("myjavascriptfn", null);
```

for more detail see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301841.aspx)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I get the error : 'Page' does not contain a definition for 'Controls'

Comment: @IrApp you are using asp.net or C# (windows form or console application)?

Comment: well, I am using C#.

Comment: @IrApp it is windows form or console application?

Comment: @IrApp if it is web means `.aspx` page then you can also use `this.Controls.Add` in pace of `Page.Controls.Add`

Comment: It is a Universal Windows Apliccation and it contains a webView

Comment: @IrApp are you using `WebBrowser` control?

Comment: I am using web view control

Comment: @IrApp i modified my answer, please check this.